# Can't get the max 30 fps my webcam supports with OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

I'm playing with OpenCV and two webcams (Logitech C525, max 720p@30fps and TedGem 1080, max 1080p@30fps). I would like to write to disk those 30 fps, but I'm only getting ~28 for the Logitech and ~24 for the TedGem.

My approach is: launch a thread that reads frames and writes them to disk, wait for 5 seconds using usleep, and raise a stop flag. Theoretically, I should have recorded ~150 frames (30fps, 5 seconds), but I only get 140 for the Logitech and 117 for the TedGem. Is this a hardware limitation, or is there something wrong with the code? Is is possible to save raw images, and not jpg compressed ones so I can maybe save some time?

I've tried also with separate threads for writing and reading, and even different resolutions, with the same results.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "iostream"
#include "thread"
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace cv;

VideoCapture camera(0);
bool stop = false;
int fc = 0;

void saveFrames()
{
    while(!stop)
    {
        Mat frame;
        camera >> frame;
        // camera.read(frame); // same results with this one
        cv::imwrite("frames/frame" + std::to_string(fc) + ".jpg", frame);
        fc++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    if(!camera.isOpened())
        return -1;

    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);
    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,30);

    double fps = camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

    std::thread tr(saveFrames);
    usleep(5e6);
    stop = true;
    tr.join();
    std::cout << "Written " << fc << " frames of " << fps * 5 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If, instead of using threading, I just call the read routine 300 times to get 300 frames, even without calling imwrite, and use std::chrono to count the time, I get 10.35 seconds for the 300 frames (~28.91fps).

More data after more testing: I've switched to std::chrono in order to measure the time since the polling start until the end. It does not seem to be a noticeable difference between a threaded and non-threaded version, or between a read-image-only and read-and-write versions. According chrono, I almost reach 29 fps with the Logitech but still 26.5 fps with the TedGem.

Comment: In edited version of you said ~29 fps is acceptable cos you can not except it to give exactly 30 frames for each second but 24 is not acceptable. I ll try your code asap.

Comment: I get 28.91 on average, using std::chrono, both for the threaded version and the unthreaded one. But f I use usleep to wait for the thread 10 seconds, I get 289 frames out of 300 (also 28.9 fps). It seems a hardware limit, but acceptable as you said.

Comment: Also, waiting for 5 seconds instead of 10, I get 140 frames out of 150 (~28fps). All this data is for the Logitech cam.

Comment: can you try to reduce the resolution? Can you try to remove the imwrite (you could write a tiny dummy file instead for counting - jpeg compression isn't free!). If you reach 30 fps there, you'll have additional information about the possible reasons. Did you monitor your processor/harddisk usage during recording? Are there any bottlenecks visible? Did you compute the needed bandwidth of 1280x720x24bitx30fps? Is that even possible with your connection (usb?)? Can you monitor the connection (usb?)?

Comment: I tried with two web cam now, both gave me 33 frames and 31 frame with your code. I think its about the camera. To be sure you can check in an another computer also.

Comment: @Micka I've tried also with 640x480 with the same results, and the processor doesn't seem to be having any trouble, looking at htop. Even without writing, same results. As Yunus pointed out, seems a hardware cap. But I'll check in another pc. Thank you both!

Comment: if it is a bandwidth limit, maybe the camera has different processing modes which are more efficient for transmission (like raw data instead of rgb24 or compressed jpg or h264)

Comment: How can I get the raw data from the camera? As for my usb connection, it is 3.0

Comment: I don't know whether the camera and/or opencv support it all. I don't even know whether the camera is sending with rgb24 ;)

Comment: Your threading isn't helping you at all. You need to do multiple things at once to make use of threads. Say your `read()` from the camera takes 30ms and your `write()` to disk takes 20ms, your camera will sit idle for 20ms in every 50ms while you write to disk, so it will only ever achieve 60% of its max frame rate. You need to have one thread just doing `read camera(); read camera(); read camera()` and another thread doing `write to disk(); write to disk(); write to disk()` and they should operate in parallel (with synchronisation obviously).

Comment: Yes, I know, but that was the first thing I tried (a read thread and a write thread, synced through a mutexed buffer) and I got the exact same results, so that's why I started stripping things down.